# I want to include the xml file inside the javascript file in my INTEL XDK Project

Tags: javascript, xml, html, intel-xdk, xmldom

Im doing a hybrid application through **INTEL XDK**.

- I have my file tree like this 
  [image]
- And the code inside the file is 
  [image]
- But i'm unable get file into my project .
  I will be pleased if someone help me out . Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question will become useless if those pictures get deleted - please consider posting relevant code in the question itself (yes, directory "trees" are difficult, but not really required when describing the relative location of two files!)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes the reason for putting images is I want to know whether  what are all the possible ways to give the path location . But i will consider your suggestion . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a Cordova app (which is what the XDK creates) you cannot use absolute paths to point to the location of the html file, it doesn't work as you might expect in a Cordova webview. You have to use relative paths to address any files. The `www` directory is the "root" of your project.

Your `index.html` file is located at the top of the `www` directory, as shown in your directory tree snapshot, which I assume you got from the Brackets editor that is built into the XDK:

`www/index.html`

And your xml file is located here:

`www/js/Exact.xml`

So, given the above locations and conditions, we need a slight modification to @Jaromanda's answer:

`var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('js/Exact.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file is

```
www/js/Exact.xml
```

You're trying to access it from

```
www/xdk/index.html
```

One thing to try is

```
var xmlDoc = laodXMLDoc('../js/Exact.xml');
```

or, if www is the "root" of a web server

```
var xmlDoc = laodXMLDoc('/js/Exact.xml');
```

Otherwise, you're on your own